# rounded corners IE6

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-6, rounded-corners

I want to get rounded corners in IE6 - 9 I am using the following css code for firefox, Chrome and Safari and works fine, is there a way you can do rounded corners in IE6 without using background images?

css code:

```
.item{

   height:85px;
   line-height: 15px;
    text-align: center;


}

.item-header > div{

}
.item > div {
  background-color: #fff;
  height:85px;
  margin-bottom:10px;

}
.item-header > div:first-child{
    width:88px;
}

.item > div:first-child {
  border-radius: 10px 0 0 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px 0 0 10px;
   border-left:2px solid #ededed;

}

.item-header > div:last-child{

}

.item > div:last-child {
  border-radius: 0 10px 10px 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 10px 10px 0;
   border-right:2px solid #ededed;
   margin-top:2px solid #ededed;
     margin-bottom:2px solid #ededed;

}

.itemHeader, .itemBody, .itemFlag, .item-header-content{
    float:left;

}

.itemHeader{
    width:85px;
    padding-top:10px;
    border-top:2px solid #ededed;
    border-bottom:2px solid #ededed;
    float:left;
    height:85px;
}

.itemBody{
    width:80px;
    height:85px;
    padding-top:10px;
    border-left:1px solid #ededed;
    border-right:1px solid #ededed;
    border-top:2px solid #ededed;
    border-bottom:2px solid #ededed;
    float:left;
}

.itemFlag{
    width:80px;
    padding-top:10px;
    border-top:2px solid #ededed;
    border-bottom:2px solid #ededed;
    float:left;
    height:85px;
}

.item-header-content{
    width:82px;
    height:50px;
    float:left;

}
.item-header-content a{
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    text-align: center;
    color:#000;
}

.resize {
width: 80px;
height : auto;
margin-top:10px;

}

.Container-results{
    width:790px;
    border-spacing:0 1px;
    margin-left:1px;
    margin-right:1px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
```

Html code:

```
<div class="Container-results">

                <div class="item">
                    <div class="itemHeader"> 

                    </div>
                    <div class="itemBody"> <strong style="font-size: 100%; color: #004A9E;">Roadside</strong></div>
                    <div class="itemBody"><div class="tick"><span>included</span></div></div>
                    <div class="itemBody"><div class="tick"><span>included</span></div></div>

                    <div class="itemBody"><div class="cross"><span>not included</span></div></div>
                    <div class="itemBody"><div class="cross"><span>not included</span></div></div>
                    <div class="itemBody"><div class="cross"><span>not included</span></div></div>
                    <div class="itemBody">
                    <strong>&pound;18<sup>.25</sup></strong>
                    </div>

                    <div class="itemFlag">
                    <a class = "btn btn-buy-online-now2" href="/breakdown/buy/58/?id=kwik-fit-insurance_roadside" target="_blank"></a>
                    <a href="/breakdown/more-info/913/?KeepThis=true&amp;TB_iframe=true&amp;height=600&amp;width=765&id=kwik-fit-insurance_roadside" class="thickbox"></a> 
                     </div>
                       </div></div>
```

Comment: Add code tags to your question, it's illegible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly not. IE 6-8 don't include any sort of border-radius support. Your only solutions  are to:

- Know exactly how tall and wide your div is, and use a transparent PNG background, which still won't work on IE6. (not a great idea, makes your layout and sizing very inflexible)
- Pollute your markup horribly with images and nested divs trying to do this. (you don't want to do this either)
- Use a JavaScript library like CurvyCorners: http://www.curvycorners.net

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here: http://jonraasch.com/blog/css-rounded-corners-in-all-browsers and here: http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/rounded_corners_experiment_ie/

If you have IE6 running now, definitely try the demo from the second link (here: http://snook.ca/technical/rounded_corners/).

I don't have IE6, so I can't tell you if it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can try "Nifty Corners" should work on IE6->

http://www.html.it/articoli/nifty/index.html

Answer (score 0):

[CSS3Pie](http://css3pie.com) is *by far* the best solution to getting rounded corners in IE6/7/8. The best thing about it is that it works with the standard CSS `border-radius`, so it's completely transparent to the user if they're using any other browser.

I would heartily recommend it.

It does have a few known issues, but you'll have the same or worse with all other solutions available.

However, I would also heartily recommend not bothering to make all the frills in your site work with IE6. Sure, make the site *work* in that browser, but honestly, trying to get it looking the same in IE6 as it does in Chrome and Firefox is going to be a losing battle.

[EDIT]

One final thing: I note that your stylesheet uses the 'direct child' selector (`>`) quite a lot - eg `.item > div {...}`. Note that this selector type is not supported by IE6. Your stylesheets are going to fail badly in IE6 as things stand.

The only way around this is to use just a space between your selectors, for 'any descendant'. This works, but does change the meaning of your CSS.

IE6 also doesn't support `:first-child` or `:last-child`, both of which you've used. In fact, you'll have problems with both these in IE7 and IE8 too -- `:last-child` isn't supported at all in any version of IE except IE9, and while `first-child` is supported in IE7 and IE8, it has severe bugs if you use it in dynamic content.